# How to set the center position of the map using the google-map-react library

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I have the following code in my React class which sets the center position of the map as expected.  My issue is that when my componentDidMount completes I want to reset the center position of the map using values returned from my API.

This is what I'm trying to achieve -

- Load default map center position when the page is loading (this is working)
- When my API returns then re-center the map using the values returned from the API (this doesn't seem to work)
- Create a pin on the map using the same values returned from the API (this is working)

The code is included below.  I've tried lots of attempts but I can't get it working as I've detailed above.  Is there something I'm missing?  I just can't seem to re-center the map.

Thanks,

**React class**

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          center: {
              lat: 100, 
              lng: 100
          }
      };
```

**Inside my componentDidMount function**

```
var self = this;

Promise.all([callMyApi()]).then(([result]) => { 

    // Set map center location
    self.setState(prevState => {
        let mapCenter = Object.assign({}, prevState.center);
        mapCenter.lat = result.latitude;                 
        mapCenter.lng = result.longitude;                 
        return { mapCenter };
    });


    // Set pin location
    var pinArray = [];
    pinArray.push({
        "id": "1",
        "latitude": result.latitude,
        "longitude": result.longitude
    });
    self.setState({pins: pinArray});
```

**Usage of the react map**

```
const Pin = ({ profile }) => <div className={"pin"}><img src=".." /></div>;


<GoogleMapReact
bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "" }}
defaultCenter={this.state.center} > 
{this.state.pins.map(p => (
    <Pin
        key={p._id}
        lat={p.latitude}
        lng={p.longitude}
        profile={p}
    />
))}
```

**Attempt #1**

```
self.setState({
      center: {
          lat: result.latitude, 
          lng: result.longitude
      }
});
```

Comment: Is it intentional that you read values from `prevState.center`, but use them to set state at `mapCenter` ? I'm not seeing where `this.state.mapCenter` is used in your component.

Comment: oh maybe that's the problem, maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Have added an update but this doesn't work?

Comment: Make sure you're using the Map component properly - the [docs](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/blob/master/API.md#defaultcenter-array-or-object) suggest that you shouldn't pass a changing value as the `defaultCenter` prop.

Comment: I've updated the code to change it from defaultCenter to center but I experience the same problem

Answer (score 1):

In fact the map is not re-centered since `center` state is not getting updated here:

```
self.setState(prevState => {
    let mapCenter = Object.assign({}, prevState.center);
    mapCenter.lat = result.latitude;                 
    mapCenter.lng = result.longitude;                 
    return { mapCenter };
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
});
```

The proper syntax would be:

```
self.setState(prevState => {
    let mapCenter = Object.assign({}, prevState.center);
    mapCenter.lat = result.latitude;
    mapCenter.lng = result.longitude;
    return {center : mapCenter};
});
```

or a more direct way:

```
this.setState({
    center: {lat: result.latitude, lng: result.longitude}
});
```

Refer [State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) for a more details.